# Why can I return an Array[A] but not A using Classtag? How can I return A?

Tags: scala

In the following code, why could I return `Array[A]` but not `A`? How can I return `A`?

```
scala> import scala.reflect._

import scala.reflect._

scala> class Covariant[+A]{
     | def m[A:ClassTag]:Array[A] = new Array[A](1)
     | }
defined class Covariant

scala> class Covariant[+A]{
     | def m[A:ClassTag]:A = new A
     | }
<console>:15: error: class type required but A found
       def m[A:ClassTag]:A = new A
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact that there are classes with no default constructor (i.e. without parameters). For example, you can't create an instance of

```
case class IntWrapper(value:Int)
```

without providing some `Int` value. Moreover there is no way in Scala to express constraint that the type must have such a constructor. Thus Scala compiler can't generated any valid code for `new A`. It works for arrays because all arrays have the same shape i.e. the all have a constructor with exactly one `Int` parameter so the compiler can generate a valid call here.

Probably the best workaround you can have is to create your own typeclass for types with default constructor:

```
trait DefaultConstructor[A] {
  def create(): A
}

class Covariant[+A] {
  def m[A](implicit ctr:DefaultConstructor[A]): A = ctr.create()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... The answer is simple, you are doing different things in these two examples,

You will get the same errors if you try doing the same thing in your `Array` example,

```
scala> import scala.reflect._
// import scala.reflect._

scala> def m[A:ClassTag]:Array[A] = List(new A).toArray
// <console>:16: error: class type required but A found
//       def m[A:ClassTag]:Array[A] = List(new A).toArray
//                                             ^

scala>  def m[A:ClassTag]:A = new A
// <console>:16: error: class type required but A found
//       def m[A:ClassTag]:A = new A
//                                 ^
```

If you want it to work. You need to get the constructor from the `TypeTag` evidence,

```
import scala.reflect._

def createNewInstance[A: ClassTag] = {
  val clazz = classOf[A]
  val constructors = clazz.getConstructors
  val defaultConstructor = constructors(0)
  val instance = defaultConstructor.newInstance()
  instance.asInstanceOf[A]
}

def m[A:ClassTag]: Array[A] = List(createNewInstance[A]).toArray

def m[A:ClassTag]: A = createNewInstance[A]
```

Answer (score 0):

The *new* keyword is used to create a new instance of class. Since Array is a valid class *new Array[A](1)* is a valid statement. However, *new A* is invalid as the A is not a valid class type (the error already indicates). Hence the compile time error.

I am not sure, what you want to do, but to return a result of type A you can simply use the following instead:

```
def m[A:ClassTag](a:A) = a
```